# How do I use type annotation and function with Sqlx query builder in Rust

Tags: sql, rust, rust-sqlx

I basically have a query like this

```
INSERT INTO assets (id, events, geo) 
VALUES ($1, $2::jsonb, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($3))
```

But I will like to build using the Query builder because I want to insert multiple values. I have tried something like this

```
        let mut query_builder = QueryBuilder::new(
            r#"
            INSERT INTO assets
            (id, events, geo)
            "#,
        );

        query_builder.push_values(values, |mut builder, value| {
            builder
                .push_bind(value.id)
                .push_bind(asset.events.clone())
                .push_bind(asset.geo.clone());
        });
```

but this does not work because using `push_bind` method, I have not found a way to do the type assertion `2::jsonb` and the function call `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($3)` needed in the query.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I don't think this is really something `QueryBuilder` is designed to do. If you want to build more complex queries in Rust, you may want to use `sea-query` instead, though note this requires you to generate/write appropriate `Iden` implementations for your schema.